# Prompting for password during Ansible playbook running

Tags: ansible, passwords, vpn, openvpn

I am attempting to write an ansible playbook to send out to new colleagues that would automate a few of the tasks that they would need to do once getting a new laptop (installing standard programs and connecting to OpenVpn etc)  I am stuck at how I would get them to input their password at the time of starting the VPN service.  If I use the --ask or -k options at the beginning of the playbook running it (the password) will likely time-out before the playbook gets to starting the service. The passwords are using a 2FA type password where they put in their PIN and then use a token to generate the second half of their password so it will time out after a set period.  I thought of vars_prompt but unsure where it would be passed in and if it would work.  I am using somthing like this:

```
- name: start and enable openvpn
  ansible.builtin.service:
    name: "{{ openvpn_service }}"
    state: started
    enabled: yes
```

but of course it times out as there isnt a prompt for a password.  Happy for any advice or help

Answer (score 0):

You can ask for a password during the script with a specific task:

```
- name: "Ask for credentials"
  pause:
    prompt: "Enter VPN 2FA: "
    echo: no
  register: 2fa_password
```

Then in the VPN Connection task, you can use the result with `2fa_password.user_input`.